# Phone says that it is "up-to-date" after a canceled update

Tags: updates, 5.1-lollipop, 6.0-marshmallow

I have canceled a Marshmallow update download by accident, and now when I got to check for updates, the phone says that the device software is up-to-date.  How can I fix this?

Phone: Moto G 3rd Generation
OS: Android 5.1.1

EDIT:  Unfortunately I cannot check solutions because recently the phone asked me to update to Marshmallow again, and this time I accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try clearing data for the updater app under Settings -> Apps

Try checking for update after this.

I'm not sure whats the exact name of app in AOSP/Moto G rom.
For CM the name of app is cmupdater.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Elena : Your update might be stored in cache partition.

Comment: @Firelord:  I cleared the cache partition, but it didn't work.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could either try to clear the whole cache of your phone via `Settings > Storage & USB > Cache > Clear cache`or you could try to update through Motorola's desktop app.

Comment: OTAs (updates "over the air" to your device) are often distributed in waves to reduce server usage and affect fewer users with errors that could be found in an OTA. By cancelling the download, you may have missed your chance in this wave and the server will only tell your device that an update is available in a later wave. However, the PC companion app shouldn't be affected by this.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot check your answer anymore, because recently the phone asked me to update to Marshmallow again, and this time I followed through.

Comment: good for you, I guess :)